# Is it possible to add a RangeSelector for date on a hidden highchart xAxis?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Here is a fiddle that I have [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/lucywilcox/j49mh46y/12/). In this fiddle, what I would like to to is to add a `RangeSelector` on the x axis of the graph. I want to be able to view 'Vulnerabilities per Version' that span 1yr, 3yr, 5yr, and 10yr. However, I am unsure of how to go about this. From the numerous fiddles I've seen on stack overflow and blogs, I'm wondering if this is possible. For example, the mockups I saw on other fiddles show that `HighStocks` is the way I would want to go. However, I think that's not exactly what I'm looking for.

Ideally what I would like is to have a graph that looks like the one found on the highstock web page [Highstock range example](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/range-selector) but I don't want the range selector underneath the xaxis, nor do I want the labels to be of dates. I only want the functionality of sorting the info by the buttons on top. Does anyone know of a way I an try this? Help would be appreciated

Comment: Using Highstock.js library, you can add rangeSelector to your chart: https://jsfiddle.net/j49mh46y/13/ But I don't know how you would like to sort your data in dates without dates

Comment: Additionally, you can add custom buttons to your chart with renderer.button() method: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.button